Golang template function returns content of index.html instead of page
I try to create web application via this tutorial, but
localhost:3000 shows content of index.html instead of page. What is wrong with my code?

index.html result

main.go
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

var tpl = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("index.html"))

func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    tpl.Execute(w, nil)
}

func main() {
    port := os.Getenv("PORT")
    if port == "" {
        port = "3000"
    }

    mux := http.NewServeMux()

    mux.HandleFunc("/", indexHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":"+port, mux)
}

index.html
<DOCTYPE>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Orders</title>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/style.css"> -->
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Orders12</h1>
</body>
</html>

go version go1.22.4 windows/amd64
if I replase tmpl.Execute(w, nil) with w.Write([]byte("<h1>HELLO W</h1>")) - it wokrs, so server is ok. Maybe proble is in tmpl.Execute(w, nil)

The first line in index.html should be <!DOCTYPE html> (see MDN).

@Brits thx but result is same. Any way problem is solved if I remove <!DOCTYPE html> or <!DOCTYPE> completely XD

Hmm, works for me. Please try this (tested with Firefox and Chrome) - you will need to copy/paste the code as it will not work in the playground.

haha) Thank you a lot) I forgot about ! before DOCTYPE) You're completely right! Mb you want to add your solution like answer for closing this question?)

No worries, note that including this line is important because without this the browser may run in quirks mode.

As per the comments, the first line should be <!DOCTYPE html> (playground). See MDN for more info.
